# launchnavigator plugin building with error in phonegap buid

Tags: phonegap-plugins

Today the phonegap build issue an error with launchnavigator plugin,the following error is displayed on the build log:
Failed to install 'uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator': Error: Variable(s) missing: GOOGLE_API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID, any thought?

Comment: This was working fine forever, hopefully it's not a new Google implementation that the plugin is missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [plugin's CHANGELOG](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500), there's a new major version `5.0.0` which contains this change:

> Add plugin variable to enable specification of Google API key for geocoding on Android. Fixes [#211](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator/issues/211).

So you will need to add the plugin variable as outlined in the [updated plugin documentation](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator#phonegap-build):

```
<plugin name="uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator" source="npm" >
    <variable name="GOOGLE_API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="{your_api_key}" />
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes indeed I just saw that on the plugin documentation, now everything is back to normal - Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Worth to try this command line to include in your project as well

`$ cordova plugin add uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator --variable GOOGLE_API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="{your_api_key}"`

Comment: I feel this should be the recommended way and the right answer. Worked for me. Thank you